# Why does the fixed point theorem hold for every lambda term?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, lambda-calculus

Can someone give a clear and simple answer for why the fixed point theorem holds for every $\lambda$-term, in contrast with the fact that not all numerical function
have a fixed point?

Comment: Very simply: $\lambda$-terms are not the same as numerical functions.

Comment: In my current (non-)understanding, I would rather reverse the question: How *can* you apply the fixed point theorem for $\lambda$-terms to numerical functions? I asked this in http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27322/fixed-points-in-computability-and-logic but don't know the answer yet.

Comment: One might say that every numerical function has a fixed point, but the fixed point might not be a number.  For example, there is a family of lambda terms that model the natural numbers, and a lambda term $S$ that models the numerical function $x\mapsto x+1$, and $S$ has a fixed point, but the fixed point of $S$ is not one of the terms that models a number.

Comment: @MJD function x↦x+1 has the fixed point in λ-calculs not in arithmetic. and my question is about reason the existence of fixed point in λ-calculs.

Answer (score 2):

Numerical functions typically accept only numbers as arguments, whereas lambda-terms can accept other lambda-terms.

For your example, $\lambda x.x+1$, the following is a fixed point:

$$ Y(\lambda x.x+1)$$

where $Y$ is Turing's Y-combinator: $Y=UU$ and $U=\lambda ux.x(uux)$

This is a fixed point because:

$Y(\lambda x.x+1) = UU(\lambda x.x+1) = (\lambda ux.x(uux))U(\lambda x.x+1) = (\lambda x.x+1)(UU(\lambda x.x+1)) = (\lambda x.x+1)(Y(\lambda x.x+1))$

(using '=' loosely for congruence or $\beta$-reduction)

We have shown $(\lambda x.x+1)(Y(\lambda x.x+1))$ is $\beta$-equivalent to $Y(\lambda x.x+1)$, meaning that $Y(\lambda x.x+1)$ is a fixed point of $\lambda x.x+1$

Turing's Y-combinator will actually find a fixed point for any lambda-term $X$. That is, following the steps above but generalizing the example $\lambda x.x+1$ to any $X$, we get $X(YX)=_\beta YX$, so $YX$ is a fixed point of $X$. This is essentially the proof of the fixed point theorem.

$Y(\lambda x.x+1)$ is a lambda-term, so it's not a numerical fixed point of $x \rightarrow x+1$

Answer (score 0):

As was noted by others lambda terms are more general than numerical functions so you are able to draw answer(fixed point) from different set. While for numerical function e.g. $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ your fixed point must belong to $\mathbb{R}$. On contrary lambda terms reduces to other lambda terms some of them can designate numbers from $\mathbb{R}$ some of them do not designate the numbers.

For more rigorous explanations you should read some proofs of fixed point theorem for lambda calculus.